# Javascript FileReader onSuccess

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a function that looks like this:

```
async handleFile(e){
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = async function(f){                
            await somelibrary.load(f.target.result)
            await somelibrary.render()
            await someotherlibrary.init()
        }
            await reader.readAsText(file);  
        
    }
```

I need to know if the load and render has worked, at least if they haven't thrown an exception. So my idea was to do something like this:

```
async handleFile(e){
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = async function(f){
            try {                
                await somelibrary.load(f.target.result)
                await somelibrary.render()
                await someotherlibrary.init()
                return true
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                return false
            }
        }
        var rendered = await reader.readAsText(file);  
        console.log(rendered)
        
    }
```

But this only logs undefined. I understand why, my function only waits for the reading part and not for the actual handling of the content in the .onload... But how do I do this correctly?

Comment: why do you declare the onload-callback async?

Comment: thanks. yeah, I forgot to include the awaits we have for loading and rendering. the rendering part takes 2-3 seconds and the other library needs to initialize after the rendering is done

Comment: If you only want to read as UTF8 don't even bother with a FileReader, do directly `const txt = await file.text();` FileReader should be avoided as much as possible these days.